# Does the ROWID datatype exist in DB2/400?

Tags: types, db2-400, rowid

I'm working on a multi-database project. We use in this project DB2/400 and we need to know the properties of a table column.

The purpose is to determine if this column is of **ROW ID type**

With **SQLServer**, the equivalent command is :

```
select object_NAME (ID) as ObjectName, Name as IdentityColumn from syscolumns
where COLUMNPROPERTY (id, name, 'IsIdentity') = 1 and
object_NAME (ID) = 'Table_Name';
```

This statement lists the ROW ID column of the specified table.

I am looking for the equivalent command with DB2/400.

I tried to query the table ***QADBIFLD*** of "qsys", but no column seems to contain the information.

I think there must be a system table in "QSYS" that can provide this information, but I can not get my hands on it.

If anyone has an idea, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First note that ROWID is usually a term applied to Oracle's ROWID pseudocolumn...

You're simply looking for auto-genterated identity columns...

In Db2 for i...

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name
from qsys2.syscolumns
where is_identity = 'YES'
```